# Ionic middleware like Laravel

Tags: laravel, ionic-framework, middleware

Is there a way to make some sort of middleware in Ionic in a way that Laravel has?

So I have several controllers, and in every controller I would like to check if token exists in local storage. Seems kind of redundant to copy/paste the code all over again

Comment: which ionic version? v1 or v2?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there isn't a middleware like Laravel, but what you can do is listening for state changes.

```js
(function (){
  'use strict';
  angular.module('Your_Module', ['ionic', 'wtv_more'])
  .run(['$rootScope', '$ionicPlatform', '$state', function($rootScope, $ionicPlatform, $state) {

    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
      //your ionic stuff
    });

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(e, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
      // we check if we are not on the index screen so we don't have a infinite loop of redirects
      // and we also check if there's a token on the sessionStorage
      if(!~toState.name.indexOf('app.home') && sessionStorage.token !== 'something'){ 
        e.preventDefault();
        $state.go('app.home'); //redirect user back to home
      }
    });
  }]);
})();
```